# drush site install to a different database host

Tags: drush

I created a new Drupal site from a PHP script on a web server. The web server and database server is on different hardware, different ip addresses.

`drush si --db-url=mysql://mytest:mytest@dbserver:8080/mytest` works only if dbserver is localhost. If apache has a different ip address, the database user has the incorrent ip address.
i.e instead of being `dbuser@webserver_ipaddress` it is `dbuser@dbserver_ipaddress`.

Is there any option to specify the correct `ipaddress` for the user?

Comment: Well I see you are specifying the wrong port on the DB host, potentially. Also, what are describing is correct. The DB user string will use the dbuser@dbserver_ipaddress - you told it too. Typo?